# Export C++ function with a callback function as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, callback

i have a c++ function called DoAllWork in a dll.
there is a c# wrapper around it.
i created a delegate in the c# wrapper and i'm passing it as a callback to the c++ function in the dll.

my c# code is as follows:

```
 public delegate int UpdateDelegate(int status);

            public static int UpdateDelegate(int status)
            {
                return status;
            }

            [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
            public static extern int DoAllWork( string param1, string param 2,... UpdateDelegate callbackproc);
        }
```

i declared the DoAllWork function in the c++ header file and implement it in the cpp file as follows:

.h file:

```
int DoAllWork(string param1, string param 2,... int (*statusfunction(int))
```

.cpp file :

```
int DoAllWork(string param1, string param 2,... int (*statusfunction(int))
 {
//do work;
}
```

then we export the c++ function DoAllWork from a third cpp file called ExportAll.cpp
the code is as follows:

```
EXPORT_FUNC Init(const char* path)
{
    cppLibrary = new CPPLibrary();
    return cppLibrary->Init(path);
}

EXPORT_FUNC DoAllWork(string param1, string param 2,..., 
int(*statusfunction(int))
        )
{
return cppLibrary->DoAllWork(string param1, string param 2,..., ??????);
}
```

My problem is that i'm getting an error whatever way i try to pass argument for the last parameter ( int(*statusfunction(int)))

any idea how to pass a parameter while exporting a c++ function with a callback function as a parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Don't make us guess which error you get...

Comment: Are you getting a compile time error? Runtime error? What error, specifically?